# XML - How do I access an attribute of an element?

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion.  I am trying to access an attribute of an element and can't quite figure out how to do it.  The name of the element is Package.  The name of the attribute is ID.  I need to get the Package ID.

```
<cfset Packages = xmlSearch(MyXMLDoc, '/IntlRateV2Response/Package')>
```

I have uploaded an image of the id that I am trying to get at.

```
http://evikjames.com/SteinAir/xml.jpg
```

I swear I have tried every possible combination and looked everywhere for the answer. But, luck. Can you help?

I have tried the solutions offered below. I can't get it to work for me.  It seems that I successfully put the value of the Package ID into a variable, but it's just an array. I can't seem to access it in the array.  Here's my error:

```
Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
```

Here's the code I am using:

```
<cfset PackageID = xmlSearch(MyXMLDoc, 'Package/Package/@ID[i]')>
<cfset Observations = xmlSearch(MyXMLDoc, "    Package/Observations[i]")>
```

I can output Observations, but I can't output PackageID.

What's up?

Comment: Maybe something like .. ? `<cfset arr = xmlSearch(MyXMLDoc, '/IntlRateV2Response/Package[ index ]/@ID')><cfoutput>#arr[1].xmlValue#</cfoutput>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you follow [this guide](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/960-Ask-Ben-Selecting-XML-Attributes-Given-Other-XML-Attributes.htm), the following should work for you (essentially, this is XPath syntax):

```
<cfset IdAttributes= xmlSearch(MyXMLDoc, '/IntlRateV2Response/Package/@ID')>
```

Comment: +1 Just use "@id" rather than @ID if your document is case sensitive.

Comment: @Leigh: XML is always case sensitive. Looking at his picture, it's really `ID`, not `id` ;)

Comment: Huh.. for some reason I always thought xmlParse's `caseSensitive` parameter would affect case sensitivity with certain operations. It does not (at least not how I was thinking) ;) Well don't I feel silly now. But you are right. Too bad I cannot +1 you twice!

Comment: Abel's example should an array. Just use `xmlValue` to grab the ID ie `<cfdump var="#IdAttributes[ index ].xmlValue#">`

Comment: @Evik: it's an array because it returns all `@ID` from all `Package` elements. Specify the package you want the `@ID` from and you should be fine. Check Leigh's comment under your main thread to see how.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Fixed case of attribute name per comments

If only the "id" is needed, Abel's approach is slicker. But if you need to process other information as well, either of these should work.  Just watch for case sensitivity issues.

```
<cfxml variable="str">
    <IntlRateV2Response>
        <Package ID="123">a</Package>
        <Package ID="456">b</Package>
        <Package ID="789">c</Package>
    </IntlRateV2Response>
</cfxml>

<cfset MyXMLDoc = xmlParse(str)>
<cfset packages = xmlSearch(MyXMLDoc, '/IntlRateV2Response/Package')>

<cfloop array="#packages#" index="pack">
    <cfoutput>
        #pack.xmlAttributes["ID"]# OR
        #pack.xmlAttributes.ID#  
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```